# Python Lists : Why new list object gets created after concatenation operation?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I was going through the topic about list in Learning Python 5E book.
I notice that if we do concatenation on list, it creates new object. Extend method do not create new object i.e. In place change. 
What actually happens in case of Concatenation?

For example

```
l = [1,2,3,4]
m = l
l = l + [5,6]
print l,m

#output
([1,2,3,4,5,6], [1,2,3,4])
```

And if I use Augmented assignment as follows,

```
l = [1,2,3,4]
m = l
l += [5,6]
print l,m

#output
([1,2,3,4,5,6], [1,2,3,4,5,6])
```

What is happening in background in case of both operations?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two methods being used there: `__add__` and `__iadd__`.  `l + [5, 6]` is a shortcut for `l.__add__([5, 6])`.  `l`'s `__add__` method returns the result of addition to something else.  Therefore, `l = l + [5, 6]` is reassigning `l` to the addition of `l` and `[5, 6]`.  It doesn't affect `m` because you aren't changing the object, you are redefining the name.  `l += [5, 6]` is a shortcut for `l.__iadd__([5, 6])`.  In this case, `__iadd__` changes the list.  Since `m` refers to the same object, `m` is also affected.

**Edit**: If `__iadd__` is not implemented, for example with immutable types like `tuple` and `str`, then Python uses `__add__` instead.  For example, `x += y` would be converted to `x = x + y`.  Also, in `x + y` if `x` does not implement `__add__`, then `y.__radd__(x)`, if available, will be used instead.  Therefore `x += y` *could* actually be `x = y.__radd__(x)` in the background.

Comment: Note there is an important caveat here: Immutable types don't implement `__iadd__`, and for any object with `__add__` but not `__iadd__`, Python silently uses `__add__` to perform the operation. So with `tuple`s, when you do `a = (1, 2)`, `b = a`, `a += (3, 4)`, since `tuple`s are immutable, it's really as if the last statement was `a = a + (3, 4)`, in that `a` gets replaced with a whole new `tuple`, and `b` continues to reference the original `(1, 2)` `tuple`.

Comment: Nice. I like the addition on `__radd__`.

Answer (score 5):

You can understand this better by inspecting the objects referenced in memory. Lets use [`id` for the inspection](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#id)

In the first case:

```
>>> l = [1,2,3,4]
>>> id(l)
4497052232
>>> m = l
>>> id(m)
4497052232
>>> l = l + [5,6]
>>> id(l)
4497052448
>>> print l, id(l), m, id(m)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] 4497052448 [1, 2, 3, 4] 4497052232
>>>
```

Notice that `l = l + [5,6]` creates a new object in memory, and `l` references that.

In the second case:

```
>>> l = [1,2,3,4]
>>> id(l)
4497052520
>>> m = l
>>> id(m)
4497052520
>>> l += [5,6]
>>> id(l)
4497052520
>>> print l, id(l), m, id(m)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] 4497052520 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] 4497052520
>>>
```

`l += [5,6]` references to the same object in memory. Hence the result. 
So, basically `+=` is the equivalent of inplace add.. [More on this can be read here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.__iadd__)